# Get user input as key value pair and search in the data through API using jQuery Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, oracle-jet

I would like to know is there any library available where the page can get the user input as key, value pair `(example : name1=value name2=value2)`and then search the data through API. The search process can be done using plain Javascript which doesn't have any issues, but I have requirement to get the user input in such way. I tried to search a lot in Google to try to find out the way where I ended up nothing.

Note : Am using Oracle JET to develop the site where I don't find any component to support this kind of input search, so thinking of implement such feature using jQuery library if anything available.

Comment: Can you elaborate what's your requirement is. We can't make any inference with the above description. Its very easy to construct the query string with the user selected values

Comment: My requirement is to get the user input in the format of `key1=value1 key2=value2` and send its hash data to the ViewModel. Then in the ViewModel I can handle it by parsing it and proceed further with it.

Comment: what is that control user gives input? Is it inputText/combobox/textarea??

Comment: it will be free text box, but the `key` should be selectable in the list which should be displayed while user focus on the text box and the `value` is completely free text where user will type it.